Deadlock with different indexes in use
Following test case causes a deadlock in SQL Server but not in Oracle.
Process 1 selects the primary key column a record with an exact hit where clause. Using one index.
Process 2 selects the same record form a table in fifo like manner using row level locking and another index and blocks as expected.
Process 1 deletes the record by primary key.
With SQL Server this causes a deadlock.
With Oracle no deadlock occurs.
Is there a way to avoid the deadlock in SQL Server?
Below you'll find more details about how to reproduce and compare the behavior.
SQL SERVER
SQL Server version 2019 ond Windows 10
Setup
create table deadlocktest (
  pk int, 
  id1 int, 
  id2 int, 
  x int, 
  y int, 
  seq int, 
  primary key nonclustered  (pk) );

create UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED index  idx_id1 on deadlocktest(id1, x, seq);
create UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED index  idx_id2 on deadlocktest(id2);
create UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED index  idx_seq on deadlocktest(seq);
  
insert into deadlocktest values (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1);
insert into deadlocktest values (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000, 2);

Options READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION are enabled.
Test case
Autocommit is off, transaction isolation level = READCOMMITTED.
T1: BEGIN TRANSACTION;
T2: BEGIN TRANSACTION;
T1: select top 1 pk, x from deadlocktest WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) where id2 = 100 and x = 1000 and seq = 1;
T2: select top 1 pk, x from deadlocktest WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) where id1 = 10 and x = 1000  order by seq;
    BLOCKED
T1: delete from deadlocktest where pk = 1;
T2: DEADLOCK ERROR

The same occurs if the select in T1 doesn't use UPDLOCK ROWLOCK. It is only used in this test case to get control over the sequence of execution.
The deadlock graph is:

The left side (victim) is the T2 select statement, the right side is the T1 insert statement.
The query plans are (you'll see different indexes are in use):
select top 1 pk, x from deadlocktest WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) where id1 = 10 and x = 1000  order by seq
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000]))
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[idx_id1]), SEEK:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[id1]=(10) AND [XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[x]=(1000)) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)

select top 1 pk, x from deadlocktest WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK) where id1 = 10 and x = 1000 and seq = 1
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000]))
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[idx_seq]), SEEK:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[seq]=(1)) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]),  WHERE:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[id1]=(10) AND [XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[x]=(1000)) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)

delete from deadlocktest where pk = 1
  |--Table Delete(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest]), OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[PK__deadlock__321403CE902EA0FE]), OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[idx_id1]), OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[idx_id2]), OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[idx_seq]))
       |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[PK__deadlock__321403CE902EA0FE]), SEEK:([XGEN].[dbo].[deadlocktest].[pk]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[@1],0)) ORDERED FORWARD)

ORACLE
Oracle XE 18 on Windows 10
Setup
create table deadlocktest (
  pk int, 
  id1 int, 
  id2 int, 
  x int, 
  y int, 
  seq int, 
  primary key (pk) );
  
insert into deadlocktest values (1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 1);
insert into deadlocktest values (2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000, 2);

create UNIQUE index  idx_id1 on deadlocktest(id1, x, seq);
create UNIQUE index  idx_id2 on deadlocktest(id2);
create UNIQUE index  idx_seq on deadlocktest(seq);

Test case
Autocommit is off, transaction isolation level = READCOMMITTED.
T1: SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
T2: SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE;
T1: select pk, x  from deadlocktest where id2 = 100 and x = 1000 and seq = 1 for update;
T2: select pk, x from deadlocktest where id1 = 10 and x = 1000  order by seq for update;
    BLOCKED
T1: delete from deadlocktest where pk = 1;

No deadlock, T1 completes the delete statement, T2 keeps blocking until T1 ends.
The query plans are (you'll see different indexes are in use):
select pk, x from deadlocktest where id1 = 10 and x = 1000  order by seq for update;
SELECT STATEMENT
  FOR UPDATE
    BUFFER (SORT)
      XGEN.DEADLOCKTEST  TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID)
        XGEN.IDX_ID1  INDEX (RANGE SCAN)

select pk, x  from deadlocktest where id2 = 100 and x = 1000 and seq = 1 for update;
SELECT STATEMENT
  FOR UPDATE
    XGEN.DEADLOCKTEST  TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID)
      XGEN.IDX_ID2  INDEX (UNIQUE SCAN)

Additonal Informtation
The select with locking in T1 is used for this test scenario to get control over the concurrent transactions. In real application context this select is missing and the deadlock as shown above in the deadlock graph.

Are the transactions running in the READ COMMITTED isolation level? I would not expect blocking or deadlock due to the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option unless hints are specified.

@DanGuzman - "unless hints are specified". Honest question, but they did specify UPDLOCK, which I would expect to block. Is that your understanding as well? Also, fwiw, the test cases are slightly underspecified insofar as there are impled begin transaction statements in there not not listed in the test cases.

For T1 you can use WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK, INDEX = idx_id1 ) to ensure that it uses the same access path as T2. Otherwise both can get a U lock on the keys in different indexes. Only one succeeds in getting the U lock on the RID and then deadlock happens when the one with the RID lock tries to get the lock in the other index

Adding WITH( ..., INDEX = idx_id1) in T1's select seems to work. However this also influences the optimizer, we'll check impact on query performance.

T1 and T2 run in an open transaction (no autocommit), I've added star tran statements and a hint about isolation level.

@BenThul, right, the UPDLOCK hint overrides the READ_COMMITTTED_SNAPSHOT database option and result in a block on the same row. I assume the actual test has explicit transactions (or autocommit off). My point is the statement: "same occurs if the select in T1 doesn't use UPDLOCK ROWLOCK." should not be true since because SELECT queries will not acquire locks with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option. However, concurrent modifications could block/deadlock since those always acquire locks.

This deadlock is plan-dependent.  It could happen on Oracle too if the optimizer chose that plan.  So this is a bug in your code, and you should hint the index on Oracle too.
As @Martin Smith said

For T1 you can use WITH (UPDLOCK ROWLOCK, INDEX = idx_id1) to ensure that it uses the same access path as T2. Otherwise both can get a U lock on the keys in different indexes.

As for

Adding WITH( ..., INDEX = idx_id1) in T1's select seems to work. However this also influences the optimizer

Of course it does.  That's the whole point.  You've introduced a table design that will cause deadlocks if the optimizer chooses the "wrong" index.  The optimizer isn't going to select indexes in a way that avoids the deadlock unless you instruct it to.

If tweaked the test case to force the situation you assume. One query uses id1 column and the other query uses the id2 coulmn. The execution plans show diffetent index use in SQLServer and Oracle. For Oracle I've addes the execution plan for your reference. The test case doesn't show a deadlock in Oracle.

Whether you manage to replicate the deadlock in Oracle is not particularly relevant.  Your scenario requires SQL Server to use the same index for both operations, so you need query hints, or a simpler table design.
